# Why don't I have some settings in GameMaker?

Tags: game-maker

I recently bought GameMaker for Mac, however upon watching a few GameMaker videos I've realized that I don't have all options available.

For example, in "Sound Properties" in other videos people have the option to change the volume and the pan, whereas I don't.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Gamedev.SE! In order to get someone to answer this, i think that version information of your GameMaker could be useful. You say "For example", is there lots of options missing? Edit your question to have more details about the issue, to up your chances on getting the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable "advanced mode" in GameMaker. From the "File" menu, choose the "Advanced Mode" option.